# What are the effects of this define preprocessor directive?

Tags: c, pointers, c-preprocessor

I wouldn't see the point, but it seems like this is a function:

```
#define GET_BE2(ptr) ((uint16_t)(ptr)[0] << 8 | (ptr)[1])
```

I need to understand what this line means, but I can't. 
To my understanding, you would be able to put something like:

```
int *my_ptr = 1234;
int var;
var = GET_BE2(my_ptr);
```

This is probably super wrong but I just wanted to clearly state what I do not understand. I also cannot tell what

```
   ((uint16_t)(ptr)[0] << 8 | (ptr)[1])
```

is doing. `ptr` does not mention we are working with an array, so howcome we can use the `[]`? Then I can tell we are shifting 8 bits left and *or-ing* probably what are the 8 next bits.

Comment: It's called a function-like macro.

Comment: You can use `[]` subscripting with any pointer.  Whether it is valid is a separate discussion, but the equivalence `*(ptr + idx) === ptr[idx] === idx[ptr]` is firmly built into C.  Using `idx[ptr]` is not good style; you should only see it in Obfuscated C contests and similar contexts.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni While I think that your edit proposal makes sense, it is, in my opinion a little too much "reinterpretation" of the original post. Please comment and propose the meaningful change of title to OP that way.

Comment: @Yunnosch — the OP asks “ptr does not mention we are working with an array, so how come we can use the []?”   My comment addresses that

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You seem to be reading something into that which I do not see either. But that is Ok.

Comment: Jean-Cristophe, even if it is very specific I found your question interesting (so I upvoted it) except for the fact that the subject is misleading, and could be easily closed as the n-th question about function-like macro. For this reason I proposed an edit changing the subject to _"What are the effects of this define preprocessor directive?"_. Imho it is the only way to salvage it. (CC: @Yunnosch)

Comment: Talking about the macro, I wrote and then deleted a comment about its "uint16LittleEndian to uint16BigEndian" functionality. But looking better a further cast to `char *` would be required to obtain that (and it would be questionable because if a non-pointer is passed the caller is in trouble). Without that call pointer arithmetics is dependant to the caller type, and I cannot honestly imagin a real life case in which this macro would be useful.

Comment: You could look up the operators involved (`[ ]` `|` `<<`) in documentation of the language

Answer (score 4):

#### Analyzing a macro

The macro as written is intended to be used as a function.

```
#define GET_BE2(ptr) ((uint16_t)(ptr)[0] << 8 | (ptr)[1])
```

The probable intention is to convert two successive byte values into a 16-bit integer, assuming the bytes are presented in big-endian order, so `ptr[0]` is the more significant byte and `ptr[1]` is the less significant byte.

Although there is no documentation shown, you are supposed to pass it a pointer to an array of (at least) two integers, which will then be bit-manipulated to produce a result.  Because it is a macro, there is no explicit type constraint.  Therefore, it could be invoked with any of:

```
signed   char      ptr0[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
signed   short     ptr1[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
signed   int       ptr2[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
signed   long      ptr3[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
signed   long long ptr4[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
unsigned char      ptr5[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
unsigned short     ptr6[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
unsigned int       ptr7[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
unsigned long      ptr8[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
unsigned long long ptr9[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
```

Given the data values shown, it would even produce the same result from all of these.

#### Problems with a macro

However, if any of the signed values were negative, or if a (converted) negative value was assigned to the second element (shown as `0x37` above) of any of the unsigned types other `unsigned char` (so `ptr6`..`ptr9`), then you would not get what is expected.

There can be little doubt that what is intended that `ptr` should be a pointer to two adjacent `unsigned char` values.  The macro then produces a value where the value in `ptr[0]` is the high-order 8 bits of a `uint16_t` value, and the value in `ptr[1]` is the low-order 8 bits of a `uint16_t` value.  The result would 0x2337.

If the types are bigger than `char` or if type is `signed char` (or the plain `char` type is signed), and if the value in `ptr[1]` is negative, you get different results from those intended.

#### Demonstrating the shortcomings of the macro

Here's a test program (with fairly painful repetition in it — but getting rid of the repetition is also painful, and not worth it for the two test cases shown):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define GET_BE2(ptr) ((uint16_t)(ptr)[0] << 8 | (ptr)[1])

static void test1(void)
{
    signed   char      ptr0[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    signed   short     ptr1[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    signed   int       ptr2[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    signed   long      ptr3[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    signed   long long ptr4[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    unsigned char      ptr5[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    unsigned short     ptr6[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    unsigned int       ptr7[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    unsigned long      ptr8[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    unsigned long long ptr9[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };

    unsigned long long result;

    printf("Two positive elements:\n");
    result = GET_BE2(ptr0);
    printf("ptr0[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr0[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr0[0], ptr0[1]);
    printf("signed   char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr1);
    printf("ptr1[0] = 0x%.4hX  ptr1[1] = 0x%.16hX  ", ptr1[0], ptr1[1]);
    printf("signed   short     = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr2);
    printf("ptr2[0] = 0x%.4X  ptr2[1] = 0x%.16X  ", ptr2[0], ptr2[1]);
    printf("signed   int       = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr3);
    printf("ptr3[0] = 0x%.4lX  ptr3[1] = 0x%.16lX  ", ptr3[0], ptr3[1]);
    printf("signed   long      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr4);
    printf("ptr4[0] = 0x%.4llX  ptr4[1] = 0x%.16llX  ", ptr4[0], ptr4[1]);
    printf("signed   long long = 0x%.16llX\n", result);

    result = GET_BE2(ptr5);
    printf("ptr5[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr5[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr5[0], ptr5[1]);
    printf("unsigned char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr6);
    printf("ptr6[0] = 0x%.4hX  ptr6[1] = 0x%.16hX  ", ptr6[0], ptr6[1]);
    printf("unsigned short     = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr7);
    printf("ptr7[0] = 0x%.4X  ptr7[1] = 0x%.16X  ", ptr7[0], ptr7[1]);
    printf("unsigned int       = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr8);
    printf("ptr8[0] = 0x%.4lX  ptr8[1] = 0x%.16lX  ", ptr8[0], ptr8[1]);
    printf("unsigned long      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr9);
    printf("ptr9[0] = 0x%.4llX  ptr9[1] = 0x%.16llX  ", ptr9[0], ptr9[1]);
    printf("unsigned long long = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
}

static void test2(void)
{
    signed   char      ptr0[2] = { 0x23, -0x00000037 };
    signed   short     ptr1[2] = { 0x23, -0x00003A37 };
    signed   int       ptr2[2] = { 0x23, -0x004B3A37 };
    signed   long      ptr3[2] = { 0x23, -0x5C4B3A37 };
    signed   long long ptr4[2] = { 0x23, -0x5C4B3A37 };
    unsigned char      ptr5[2] = { 0x23, -0x00000037 };
    unsigned short     ptr6[2] = { 0x23, -0x00003A37 };
    unsigned int       ptr7[2] = { 0x23, -0x4B4B3A37 };
    unsigned long      ptr8[2] = { 0x23, -0x5C4B3A37 };
    unsigned long long ptr9[2] = { 0x23, -0x5C4B3A37 };

    unsigned long long result;

    printf("One positive element, one negative element:\n");
    result = GET_BE2(ptr0);
    printf("ptr0[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr0[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr0[0], ptr0[1]);
    printf("signed   char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr1);
    printf("ptr1[0] = 0x%.4hX  ptr1[1] = 0x%.16hX  ", ptr1[0], ptr1[1]);
    printf("signed   short     = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr2);
    printf("ptr2[0] = 0x%.4X  ptr2[1] = 0x%.16X  ", ptr2[0], ptr2[1]);
    printf("signed   int       = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr3);
    printf("ptr3[0] = 0x%.4lX  ptr3[1] = 0x%.16lX  ", ptr3[0], ptr3[1]);
    printf("signed   long      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr4);
    printf("ptr4[0] = 0x%.4llX  ptr4[1] = 0x%.16llX  ", ptr4[0], ptr4[1]);
    printf("signed   long long = 0x%.16llX\n", result);

    result = GET_BE2(ptr5);
    printf("ptr5[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr5[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr5[0], ptr5[1]);
    printf("unsigned char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr6);
    printf("ptr6[0] = 0x%.4hX  ptr6[1] = 0x%.16hX  ", ptr6[0], ptr6[1]);
    printf("unsigned short     = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr7);
    printf("ptr7[0] = 0x%.4X  ptr7[1] = 0x%.16X  ", ptr7[0], ptr7[1]);
    printf("unsigned int       = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr8);
    printf("ptr8[0] = 0x%.4lX  ptr8[1] = 0x%.16lX  ", ptr8[0], ptr8[1]);
    printf("unsigned long      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
    result = GET_BE2(ptr9);
    printf("ptr9[0] = 0x%.4llX  ptr9[1] = 0x%.16llX  ", ptr9[0], ptr9[1]);
    printf("unsigned long long = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
}

int main(void)
{
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

On a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with GCC 9.2.0 and XCode 11.3.1, the output from this is:

```
Two positive elements:
ptr0[0] = 0x0023  ptr0[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   char      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr1[0] = 0x0023  ptr1[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   short     = 0x0000000000002337
ptr2[0] = 0x0023  ptr2[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   int       = 0x0000000000002337
ptr3[0] = 0x0023  ptr3[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   long      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr4[0] = 0x0023  ptr4[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   long long = 0x0000000000002337
ptr5[0] = 0x0023  ptr5[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned char      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr6[0] = 0x0023  ptr6[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned short     = 0x0000000000002337
ptr7[0] = 0x0023  ptr7[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned int       = 0x0000000000002337
ptr8[0] = 0x0023  ptr8[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned long      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr9[0] = 0x0023  ptr9[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned long long = 0x0000000000002337
One positive element, one negative element:
ptr0[0] = 0x0023  ptr0[1] = 0x00000000000000C9  signed   char      = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC9
ptr1[0] = 0x0023  ptr1[1] = 0x000000000000C5C9  signed   short     = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFE7C9
ptr2[0] = 0x0023  ptr2[1] = 0x00000000FFB4C5C9  signed   int       = 0xFFFFFFFFFFB4E7C9
ptr3[0] = 0x0023  ptr3[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  signed   long      = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4E7C9
ptr4[0] = 0x0023  ptr4[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  signed   long long = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4E7C9
ptr5[0] = 0x0023  ptr5[1] = 0x00000000000000C9  unsigned char      = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr6[0] = 0x0023  ptr6[1] = 0x000000000000C5C9  unsigned short     = 0x000000000000E7C9
ptr7[0] = 0x0023  ptr7[1] = 0x00000000B4B4C5C9  unsigned int       = 0x00000000B4B4E7C9
ptr8[0] = 0x0023  ptr8[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  unsigned long      = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4E7C9
ptr9[0] = 0x0023  ptr9[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  unsigned long long = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4E7C9
```

For the simple cases where the values in the elements of the array are small enough to fit in the range 0..SCHAR_MAX (127), the output is as expected because when the values are promoted, there are no sign bits to complicate the issues.

#### Why the macro fails

When the values are not so small, then the expression has unexpected results.

```
#define GET_BE2(ptr) ((uint16_t)(ptr)[0] << 8 | (ptr)[1])
```

Let's add a few more parentheses to that:

```
#define GET_BE2(ptr) ((((uint16_t)(ptr)[0]) << 8) | (ptr)[1])
```

The shift operator is given a promoted value for the LHS operand.  That means that `ptr[0]` is first converted to a `uint16_t` value, then that's converted to an `int` (I *am* assuming a 'normal' machine where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(uint16_t)`.  The result is shifted left 8 bits.  The RHS of the `|` operator is also promoted to `int`; the two `int` values are combined and yield a result.  Note that the conversion of a `signed char` to `int` sign-extends the value.  (I *am* assuming 2's complement representation; if you're worried about 1's complement or sign-magnitude, please adapt the test code etc to suit your environment.)

These factors lead to all sorts of extraneous bits being set in the operands to the shift and or operators, leading to 'unexpected' results.

#### Fixing the macro

To make the macro code safe, the macro needs to be written more carefully.  It can either mask with `0xFF` or cast to `uint8_t` (or `unsigned char`).

```
#define GET_BE2(ptr) (uint16_t)((((ptr)[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | ((ptr)[1] & 0xFF))

#define GET_BE2(ptr) ((((uint8_t)(ptr)[0]) << 8) | (uint8_t)(ptr)[1])
```

Using either of these, the output is the same and self-consistent:

```
Two positive elements:
ptr0[0] = 0x0023  ptr0[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   char      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr1[0] = 0x0023  ptr1[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   short     = 0x0000000000002337
ptr2[0] = 0x0023  ptr2[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   int       = 0x0000000000002337
ptr3[0] = 0x0023  ptr3[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   long      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr4[0] = 0x0023  ptr4[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   long long = 0x0000000000002337
ptr5[0] = 0x0023  ptr5[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned char      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr6[0] = 0x0023  ptr6[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned short     = 0x0000000000002337
ptr7[0] = 0x0023  ptr7[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned int       = 0x0000000000002337
ptr8[0] = 0x0023  ptr8[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned long      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr9[0] = 0x0023  ptr9[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned long long = 0x0000000000002337
One positive element, one negative element:
ptr0[0] = 0x0023  ptr0[1] = 0x00000000000000C9  signed   char      = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr1[0] = 0x0023  ptr1[1] = 0x000000000000C5C9  signed   short     = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr2[0] = 0x0023  ptr2[1] = 0x00000000FFB4C5C9  signed   int       = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr3[0] = 0x0023  ptr3[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  signed   long      = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr4[0] = 0x0023  ptr4[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  signed   long long = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr5[0] = 0x0023  ptr5[1] = 0x00000000000000C9  unsigned char      = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr6[0] = 0x0023  ptr6[1] = 0x000000000000C5C9  unsigned short     = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr7[0] = 0x0023  ptr7[1] = 0x00000000B4B4C5C9  unsigned int       = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr8[0] = 0x0023  ptr8[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  unsigned long      = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr9[0] = 0x0023  ptr9[1] = 0xFFFFFFFFA3B4C5C9  unsigned long long = 0x00000000000023C9
```

#### Using an inline function

It's unlikely that those who wrote the macro intended it to be used with anything other than a `char *`, `unsigned char *` or possibly a `signed char *` (though it is probable that `signed char *` was not even considered).  It would be better, therefore, to use a function — preferably an `inline` function — to do the job.  That forces you to use the correct type (or cast the incorrect type):

```
static inline uint16_t get_be2(const unsigned char *ptr)
{
    return (ptr[0] << 8) | ptr[1];
}
```

If for some reason, your compiler is so antiquated it won't accept `inline` (even though that has been part of Standard C for the whole of the current millennium, there are such compilers around), then simply omit the `inline`.  The compiler might even make the function inline of its own accord; it can see where it's used because it is limited to the current file, and could decide it makes sense to avoid the overhead of an actual function call.  Here's a vastly reduced test case — though this could easily be re-engineered to remove an awful lot of the repetition.  Note the explicit casts on the calls using `signed char`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline uint16_t get_be2(const unsigned char *ptr)
{
    return (ptr[0] << 8) | ptr[1];
}
#define GET_BE2(ptr) get_be2(ptr)

static void test1(void)
{
    signed   char      ptr0[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };
    unsigned char      ptr5[2] = { 0x23, 0x37 };

    unsigned long long result;

    printf("Two positive elements:\n");
    result = GET_BE2((unsigned char *)ptr0);
    printf("ptr0[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr0[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr0[0], ptr0[1]);
    printf("signed   char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);

    result = GET_BE2(ptr5);
    printf("ptr5[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr5[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr5[0], ptr5[1]);
    printf("unsigned char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
}

static void test2(void)
{
    signed   char      ptr0[2] = { 0x23, -0x00000037 };
    unsigned char      ptr5[2] = { 0x23, -0x00000037 };

    unsigned long long result;

    printf("One positive element, one negative element:\n");
    result = GET_BE2((unsigned char *)ptr0);
    printf("ptr0[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr0[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr0[0], ptr0[1]);
    printf("signed   char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);

    result = GET_BE2(ptr5);
    printf("ptr5[0] = 0x%.4hhX  ptr5[1] = 0x%.16hhX  ", ptr5[0], ptr5[1]);
    printf("unsigned char      = 0x%.16llX\n", result);
}

int main(void)
{
    test1();
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Two positive elements:
ptr0[0] = 0x0023  ptr0[1] = 0x0000000000000037  signed   char      = 0x0000000000002337
ptr5[0] = 0x0023  ptr5[1] = 0x0000000000000037  unsigned char      = 0x0000000000002337
One positive element, one negative element:
ptr0[0] = 0x0023  ptr0[1] = 0x00000000000000C9  signed   char      = 0x00000000000023C9
ptr5[0] = 0x0023  ptr5[1] = 0x00000000000000C9  unsigned char      = 0x00000000000023C9
```

#### Plain `char` vs `unsigned char` and `signed char`

There are three distinct (single-byte) character types: (plain) `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char`.  The plain `char` type can be signed or unsigned; that is an implementation decision which must be documented.  I've not bothered to show `char` in the explanation because it behaves the same as one of `signed char` (this is the way it behaves on a Mac) or `unsigned char`.  However, in practice, code is often written using plain `char`.  If you revise the function to take a plain `char` pointer, you have to ensure that it works correctly regardless of whether the plain `char` type is signed or unsigned.  In which case, you either cast the incoming `const char *ptr` to `const unsigned char *uptr = (unsigned char *)ptr;` and refer to `uptr[0]` and `uptr[1]`, or you add casts or masks as in the fixed macro variants.

#### Preferred solution

Use the `inline` function.  It enforces type correctness.  It avoids the problems with the macro entirely.  And, because this function is small enough that the compiler will almost certainly be able to inline the code, it comes at no cost compared to the macro version.

Comment: Replacing the macro with an `inline` function is a way of cutting down all the type shenanigans and should be strongly considered

Comment: @M.M — I laboured so long on the original answer shown that I forgot that I intended to discuss an `inline` function.  Thanks for the reminder — I'll fix things to include that as a sensible option.  It also dramatically reduces the number of test cases, of course.

Comment: This great answer shows how sometimes, being perseverant, a question candidate to closure can be salvaged and generates interesting answers. I'm not providing answers, anymore, but in this case it was a good thing because I could have never competed wit this answer. ;) (this comment can be flagged for deletion as soon as is read)